# Condition Expression for UpdateItem exceeding max

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a Condition on my updateItem call that is exceeding the defined max. When I run this, I will ultimately have a value of 101. Is there a way to ensure that the Conditional Expression checks the ***final value*** of the Update to prevent it from exceeding 100? Note that in my test, I increment by 1, but ultimately I will increment by arbitrary values.

```
$query = array(
  'TableName'         => $this->table_name,
  'Key'               => $this->get_query_key($obj),
  'ConditionExpression'   => 'num_completed <= :max',
  'UpdateExpression'      => 'SET num_completed = num_completed + :num',
  'ExpressionAttributeValues' => array(
    ':num' => array('N' => 1),
    ':max' => array('N' => 100)
  )
  //'ReturnConsumedCapacity' => 'TOTAL'
);
try {
  $this->dynamo_db->updateItem($query);
}
```

Comment: Did you test this against the actual DynamoDB service or DynamoDB local?